# Rails + ransack. How to customize the value field according to selected attribute including associations in ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, ransack

I'm using the advanced ransack search, and I want that when the user selects an attribute for search he/she would be able to select a value from dropdown/pre-populated list in value box. just like select box.

How can I do that?

Here is my _condition_fields.html.erb code:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.attribute_fields do |a| %>
    <%= a.attribute_select associations: [:category] %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.predicate_select %>
  <%= f.value_fields do |v| %>
    <%= v.text_field :value %>
  <% end %>
#something like this here
<%= f.select, options_for_select(SELECTED_ATTRIBUTES_ALL_VALUES), include_blank: true %>
</div>
```

[image: select box or pre-define values in highlight fields]

Comment: I got the same question. Do you figure out it ?

Answer (score 1):

You should try to make your own UI. Ransack doesn't support this.